# Why isn't Android Support Library version 22 available?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Today I noticed that Android API 22 is available so I changed target SDK of my app to 22. When I did that, Gradle started complaining that support libraries cannot have versions lower than the target SDK version.

I checked [Support Library revisions link](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) and it does show that version 22 of "v4 support library" and "v7 appcompat library" have been released. So, I bumped up their versions as well in build.gradle file. Gradle then suggested that I install the "Android Support Repository". I had it installed, but I installed it again; and Gradle continued to complain. When I checked `${android_home}/extras/android/m2repository/support-v4` it indeed did not have the version 22.0.0 folder.

I also directly opened the link https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml which was used by Support Repository installer and it indeed does not list version 22 libraries!

What is wrong here?

Comment: Check again, I am downloading it now.

Comment: Downloaded it again. I see no change. :(

Comment: where you downloaded to? maybe different place

Comment: Location, as I mentioned before, is `${android_home}/extras/android/m2repository`. I also tried deleting that folder and it was recreated when I ran the installer. Additionally I uninstalled "Android Support Library" from SDK Manger and re-installed it.

Comment: I think we have to just wait and they will come and be updated.

Comment: 22.0.0 is already available on dl.google

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After reading your question and the comments again, I understand what you are trying to say. **Currently the SDK Manager does not have the Support v22 out.**

You **CAN** download API 22 but you are **NOT** seeing support-v4. By the way, "`${android_home}/extras/android/m2repository/support-v4`" is the wrong directory.

The correct directory is: "`${android_home}/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4`".

Also, you must have it downloaded from your `build.gradle`, for example:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22 // <-- You need this
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.0' // <-- You need this

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'burrows.apps.example.admob'
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22 // <-- You need this
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile rootProject.file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = Boolean.valueOf(System.getProperty("pre-dex", "true"))
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':Lib-BurrowsApps')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0' // <-- You need this
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:6.5.87'
}
```

Source: https://github.com/jaredsburrows/BurrowsAppsExamples/blob/master/Lib-BurrowsApps/build.gradle

Google's `m2repository` works just like the normal `~/.m2/repository/`.

Comment: Oops yes I mentioned incorrect directory. Sorry for confusing others.

Comment: I had updated the build file as you suggested here, but using version `21.0.3` in dependencies caused Gradle to throw error. Currently I suppressed that using `//noinspection GradleCompatible`.

Comment: @AppleGrew I will update this post as soon as the library comes out.

Comment: @AppleGrew Go ahead and update via SDK manager. The new revision to the support library is out.

Answer (score 0):

To get the most recent version of the Android support library, I was able to do the following:

1. Install all the latest things in the SDK Manager
2. Check what [the latest revision](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html#revisions) is (22.1.0 at the time of this writing)
3. Update the `dependencies` section of build.gradle accordingly

*build.gradle*

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.+'
}
```

See also (documentation)

- [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)
- [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)
- [Support Library Features](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html)